# Simpler way to check if variable is not equal to multiple string values?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Current Code:

```
<?php

  // See the AND operator; How do I simplify/shorten this line?
  if( $some_variable !== 'uk' && $some_variable !== 'in' ) {

    // Do something

  }

?>
```

And:

```
<?php

  // See the OR operator; How do I simplify/shorten this line?
  if( $some_variable !== 'uk' || $some_variable !== 'in' ) {

    // Do something else

  }

?>
```

Is there a simpler (i.e. shorter) way to write the two conditions?

**NOTE:** Yes, they are different, and I am expecting different ways to shorten the codes.

Comment: You only removed the brackets. Please edit your sample code to reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: @CBroe See the note? Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: What it unclear about _“please edit your __sample code__ to reflect what you are actually asking”_?

Comment: @CBroe It didn't make sense over adding a NOTE at the bottom, do I didn't. To be more clear, I've made the edits you suggested. **EDIT:** Also noticed another blunder in the code, which I fixed.

Comment: First case (&&): `!in_array($some_variable, array('uk', 'in'))`, second case (||): True for _whatever_ value $some_variable has, so the whole condition is superfluous – and therefor can be “simplified” by not making this comparison at all :-)

Comment: @CBroe is right - second condition is always TRUE. But small correction to the first: in sample there's usde '!==', so TRUE as third param to the in_array should be passed.  `!in_array($some_variable, array('uk', 'in'), true)`

Comment: Thanks @Radomir, third param `true` is of course necessary to replicate the exact same behavior.

Comment: I dream with `if( $some_variable !== ('uk' OR 'in'))` and why not `if( $some_variable !== ('uk' OR 'in') AND != null)` without being declared/type EACH time :D

Answer (score 140, accepted):

For your first code, you can use a short alteration of [the answer given by
@ShankarDamodaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949968/532495) using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
if ( !in_array($some_variable, array('uk','in'), true ) ) {
```

or even shorter with `[]` notation available since php 5.4 as pointed out by @Forty in the comments

```
if ( !in_array($some_variable, ['uk','in'], true ) ) {
```

is the same as:

```
if ( $some_variable !== 'uk' && $some_variable !== 'in' ) {
```

... but shorter. Especially if you compare more than just 'uk' and 'in'.
I do not use an additional variable (*Shankar used $os*) but instead define the array in the if statement. Some might find that dirty, i find it quick and neat :D

The problem with your second code is that it can easily be exchanged with just TRUE since:

```
if (true) {
```

equals

```
if ( $some_variable !== 'uk' || $some_variable !== 'in' ) {
```

You are asking if the value of a string is not A or Not B. If it is A, it is definitely not also B and if it is B it is definitely not A. And if it is C or literally anything else, it is also not A and not B.

So that statement always (*not taking into account schrödingers law here*) returns true.

Comment: For your first answer to be identical, you'll need the [third paramter of `in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) set to true to use strict comparison.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for the in_array call.

Comment: Schrödinger reference +1.

Comment: As of php 5.4 you can also just use the shorthand `[]` instead of `array()`.

Answer (score 18):

You can make use of [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in PHP.

```
$os = array("uk", "us"); // You can set multiple check conditions here
if (in_array("uk", $os)) //Founds a match !
{
    echo "Got you"; 
}
```

Comment: And which one of the two code does that simplify? (Please see the edited question)

Comment: @CBroe That's the first thing I did. It's still unclear (to me) whether `in_array()` does `&&` or `||`.

Comment: _“Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.”_

Comment: In the above example , `uk` is the needle and it is compared to all the elements inside the array. Since `uk` exists.. a match is found.

Comment: Same as the accepted answer, you should be using strict comparison in your `in_array()` check to replicate the OP's if statement

Answer (score 4):

I like the code used by **Habchi** in comments

```
if(!($some_variable === 'uk' || $another_variable === 'in')){//do}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that might make sense especially if this test is being made multiple times and you are running PHP 7+ and have installed the `Set` class is:

```
use Ds\Set;

$strings = new Set(['uk', 'in']);    
if (!$strings->contains($some_variable)) {
```

Or on any version of PHP you can use an associative array to simulate a set:

```
$strings = ['uk' => 1, 'in' => 1];
if (!isset($strings[$some_variable])) {
```

There is additional overhead in creating the set but each test then becomes an O(1) operation. Of course the savings becomes greater the longer the list of strings being compared is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on building a function in the if statement, I'd also advise the use of in_array. It's a lot cleaner.

If you're attempting to assign values to variables you can use the if/else shorthand:

```
$variable_to_fill = $some_variable !== 'uk' ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to multi value check. Try using the following code :

```
<?php
    $illstack=array(...............);
    $val=array('uk','bn','in');
    if(count(array_intersect($illstack,$val))===count($val)){ // all of $val is in $illstack}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find it more readable to reverse your logic and use an else statement with an empty if.

```
if($some_variable === 'uk' || $another_variable === 'in'){}

else {
    // This occurs when neither of the above are true
}
```

Comment: Having an empty clause condition is not very readable code. Use a ! on your first if statement something like if( !($some_variable === 'uk' || $another_variable === 'in')){ //this occurs when neither of the above are true}.

Answer (score -1):

Some basic regex would do the trick nicely for `$some_variable !== 'uk' && $some_variable !== 'in':`

```
if(!preg_match('/^uk|in$/', $some_variable)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: DON'T. USE. REGEX. FOR. EVERYTHING. :/