# can I optimize an 'if' statement with multiple 'or' for same variable with different value in php?

Tags: php

is there any way to minimize/optimize the following if statement:

```
if($user->type == 'admin' || $user->type == 'manager' || $user->type == 'operator'){
  //do someting
}
```

Here, I am really tired of writing $user->type and || sign again and again. Besides, in somecase this types of logic unnacessarly longer.

Comment: i don't see, where this should be a duplicate?! oO

Comment: It is a duplicate, not of the question given, but of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19949923/1612146

Comment: You can solve it like this: `if(in_array($user->type,['admin', 'manager', 'operator'])`