# Simplifying greater than IF statements with multiple ANDs based on the same value

Tags: php, operators, simplification

I have a variable that I need to check against other variables to make sure it is greater than them. I've simplified the example below, but here's a working example of the desired result.

```
<?php
  $a = 5;
  $b = 4;
  $c = 3;
  $d = 2;
  $e = 1;

  if(($a > $b) && ($a > $c) && ($a > $d) && ($a > $e)){
    echo "A is the biggest";
  }else{
    echo "A is not the biggest";
  }
?>
```

My question is, is there a simpler way to write the if statement so that we don't have to have `$a` written four separate times? Something along the lines of ...

```
if($a > $b,$c,$d,$e){
```

I've seen [Simpler way to check if variable is not equal to multiple string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949923/simpler-way-to-check-if-variable-is-not-equal-to-multiple-string-values)
 but this is for checking the presence of strings.

Comment: `if($a == max($a,$b,$c,$d,$e)){` would work, check out [php's max function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write something like that:

```
if (max($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) == $a) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can have an array of strings, you can have an array of variables.

The 'most simplistic' approach would be to return the **[`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)** of the array variables, and then simply check whether `$a` is greater than that. This way you only have to do one comparison.

```
if (($a > $b) && ($a > $c) && ($a > $d) && ($a > $e)) { }
```

Can be re-written as:

```
$values = array($b, $c, $d, $e); // array(4, 3, 2, 1);
if ($a > max($values)) { } // if (5 > 4) { }
```

Hope this helps!