# Check if last character is "s" or "z"

Tags: php, strstr

is there a more gallant way to check if last character is "s" or "z" than:

```
if (substr($var, -1, 1) == "s" OR substr($var, -1, 1) == "z") ...
```

Something like

```
if (substr($var, -1, 1) == "s" OR "z") ...
```

would be nice, but is there something like this in PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simpler way to check if variable is not equal to multiple string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949923/simpler-way-to-check-if-variable-is-not-equal-to-multiple-string-values)

Answer (score 2):

Use `in_array` and looking for last character in array:

```
if (in_array(substr($var, -1, 1), ['s', 'z']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
in_array(array_pop(explode('', $var)), ['s', 'z'])` ?
```

not really much more readable neither gallant, but what do I know? :)

Answer (score 0):

Tired of code that's too easy to understand? Regular expressions to the rescue:

```
preg_match('/[sz]$/', $var)
```

Comment: Haha nice. Well, programming is not my job so I don't know what would be the state of the art. Would you rather choose my original solution as it is more readable?

Comment: I'm mostly a C++ programmer, so I view "that's clever" as a curse. Clarity and readability over cleverness. If you know regular expressions, this one is fairly clear, `[]` is "one of" and `$` is "end of string", if you don't, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I do but I figured that a regular expression would be a little bit too over-engineered and also slower, as a regular expression in general takes longer, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use PHP8, then you should this simple solution available in PHP8.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php

```
<?php
$text = 'foods';
if (str_ends_with($text, 's') || str_ends_with($text, 'z')) { ... }
```

Comment: That is equally as long though :) but thank you, didn't know that function.